# Javascript still recognize actionscript functions previously nulled with call ExternalInterface.addCallback

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3, actionscript, externalinterface

> Is there any way to make javascript recognize that function registered at actionscript with ExternalInterface.addCallback was removed by calling it again and passing null to closure reference?

I have this code at actionscript:

```
ExternalInterface.addCallback(functionName, myFunction);
```

At javascript I try to find out type of function registered:

```
var flashContent = document.getElementById("flashContent");
console.log(typeof flashContent.functionName);
```

Which produce following ouput at console:

*function*

Then I remove callback at actionscript by calling:

```
 ExternalInterface.addCallback(functionName, null);
```

But calling previous javascript check again:

```
console.log(typeof flashContent.functionName);
```

Produces the same output again:

*function*

Note that if I call this check before creating callback ExternalInterface.addCallback function I get output:

*undefined*

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I needed to call some functions in flash content.
But some functions might become unavaiable depending on state of our flash content.

I made workaround:
Created "check" function on flash that is always avaiable to js.

- It accepts one parameter - function name.
- And it returns true or false whether function with that name is currently avaiable.

Javascript can then easily know if any function on flash is avaiable just by calling this "check" function first and passing desired function's name.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11552589)

Comment: I made work around for the problem and just wanted to post it. If anyone else in the future needs it. It is NOT another question.